# Rails use associated record to group array results

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my application I have

```
class Volunteer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :reports
end

class Report < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :volunteer
end
```

each volunteer has a field which stores the category that volunteer is apart of (director, supervisor, general)

Im using a simple search form to grab all reports within a specific time period, and I would like to split the results into three separate arrays by Volunteer.category .

What would be the best way to split out the results while in the controller?

Comment: is your initial `reports` object an array or activerecord relation?

Comment: @sixty4bit thanks for your help, the results are an array directly from the Report model    where("report_month Like ?", "%#{search}%")

Comment: I *think* (not 100% sure but try running that `.where` query in your console and try `.class` on the result) that `.where`  will return an activerecord relation object, which is similar but not exactly the same as an array. Check my answer below and let me know if it works out. If not, we can try to tweak it.

Comment: @sixty4bit good call! you were right adding .class returns Report::ActiveRecord_Relation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're starting out with a collection of reports (AR relation) you could try:

`category_a = reports.joins(:volunteer).where("volunteers.category = ?", "a")`

...and so on. This would return an ActiveRecord relation object rather than an array but it is similarly enumerable and faster. If for whatever reason you really need an array you could try:

`category_a = reports.select { |report| report.volunteer.category == "a" }`

One tip for testing collection-generation like this is to try it in the console and see if it gives you want you want before adding the hassle of putting it in the controller and testing it there.